# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GPUOptions'

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I'm using dell laptop with GTX 960M, and i installed tensorflow 2.0 alpha. i used to use 1.5 version and it work with tf.GPUOptions, but in this version, this causes an `error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GPUOptions'`
someone help me if i do the thing wrong with this version

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "prepare_training.py", line 20, in 
>           gpu_option = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)
>       AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GPUOptions'

Comment: Changes to higher major version like these break backward compatibility. You cannot expect to upgrade without changing the original code.

Comment: sure! but i can not find any documents about the compatible function or config for GPUOption. thats my problem. thanks!

Comment: Just by glancing over the documentation `tf.config.gpu.set_per_process_memory_fraction(FRAC)`

Comment: thank you! i just found it!

Answer (score 24):

Tensorflow 2.x has undergone major changes from 1.x.

As per official communication,

> tf.contrib will be removed from the core TensorFlow repository and build process. TensorFlow’s contrib module has grown beyond what can be maintained and supported in a single repository. Larger projects are better maintained separately, while smaller extensions will graduate to the core TensorFlow code. A special interest group (SIG) has been formed to maintain and further develop some of the more important contrib projects going forward. Please engage with [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/pull/37) RFC if you are interested in contributing.

If you want to use the `tensorflow 1.x` functions/methods, there is a compatibility module kept in `tensorflow 2.x`.

```
tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)
```

Comment: What is per_process_gpu_memory_fraction?

Comment: @SenthilVikramVodapalli It is a config parameter, used to limit GPU usage by the tensorflow. By default, tf consumes all GPU memory.